# How can I set my loop to put different titles in the plots

Tags: python, list, loops, matplotlib, title

```
er=0
for sector in range(16):
  incl = sector in wind_sectors_df
  if incl:
    ind = [i for i in range(len(wind_sectors_df)) if wind_sectors_df[i] == sector]
    if ind:  # if ind is not empty
      for i in ind:
        df = dfs[i]
        print(times[i])
        print(wind_sectors_df[i])
        latitudes = df['floatLatitudes']
        longitudes = df['floatLongitudes']
        dlat = dx * 360.0 / (2 * np.pi * earth_radius) # latitude
        dlon = dx * 360.0 / (2 * np.pi * earth_radius * np.cos(np.nanmean(latitudes) * np.pi / 180.0))
        grid_lon = np.arange(np.nanmin(longitudes), np.nanmax(longitudes), dlon) # longitude grid
        grid_lat = np.arange(np.nanmin(latitudes), np.nanmax(latitudes), dlat)   # latitude grid
        to_grid = df['CPC_tot']
        gridded_data = np.zeros([len(grid_lat), len(grid_lon)], dtype=float) + np.nan
        for j in range(len(grid_lat) - 1):
          for i in range(len(grid_lon) - 1):
            ind = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(latitudes>=grid_lat[j],  latitudes<grid_lat[j+1]),
                            np.logical_and(longitudes>=grid_lon[i], longitudes<grid_lon[i+1]))
            if np.sum(ind) >= min_n_points:
             gridded_data[j,i] = np.nanmean(to_grid[ind]) 
        xx, yy = np.meshgrid(grid_lon, grid_lat, indexing='xy')
        fig=plt.figure()
        plt.pcolor(xx, yy, gridded_data, cmap='RdBu')
        plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal', label='CPC_tot(#/cm3)')
        plt.title('Time: {} , sector: {}'.format(times[i],sector_new_dfs[er]))
        er=er+1
```

My main problem is that everything works all right but when I try to put a title in each different plot I get this message:

```
plt.title('Time: {} , sector: {}'.format(times[i],sector_new_dfs[er]))
```

Error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But if you see when I put print(times[i]) It prints all the titles correctly... so I don't know what's happend... when I try to set the title.... 
If i remove the plt.title, all the code works good, so It's just the title...
I put the whole code, just in case you need to check something before the plt.title...

I've tried putting some words on the title and It worked, it's just to make faster the process

Comment: You have a problem that you are using the variable `i` twice. (`for i in ind` and `for i in range(len(grid_lon) - 1)`). Just rename the latter one to use another variable name.

Comment: I knew that It was something stupid, thanks a lot